# Problema con firma en Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Hace un tiempo atrás subí una app a Google Play, que Google terminó suspendiendome.

Ahora queremos volver a subir la aplicación a Google Play, pero tenemos varios problemas.

Lo primero es que no disponemos del código fuente de la aplicación, solo tenemos la APK y el keystore. La APK está muy bien ofuscada lo que hace que la Ingenieria Inversa sea casi imposible.

Lo segundo es que, al haber suspendido la app Google Play, no podemos eliminar la antigua app y subir una nueva con el mismo nombre de paquete.

Hemos intentado cambiar el nombre del paquete con aplicaciones como APK Editor Pro (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor.pro&hl=es)

Y se ha cambiado el nombre de paquete, pero al intentar subir la apk a Google Play hemos obtenido el siguiente error:

[image: Subiste un archivo APK firmado con un certificado restringido. Debes subir un archivo APK firmado con tu propio certificado.]

> "Subiste un archivo APK firmado con un certificado restringido. Debes
>   subir un archivo APK firmado con tu propio certificado."

No sabemos que podemos hacer. ¿A alguien se le ocurre una posible solución?

Muchas gracias de antemano por leer, la aplicación llegó a tener 20.000 usuarios y hay muchísima gente esperando a que vuelva.

UPDATE:

El error me daba al firmar la APK, en mi caso personal lo que he es hecho es:

1. Renombrar el paquete de la APK con APK Editor PRO
2. Firmar la APK con el paquete cambiado con APK Signer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haibison.apksigner)

Ahora Google Play si que me acepta la APK.
Muchas gracias a los que habeis intentado ayudar.
Saludos!

Comment: mmm... Interesante pregunta... pero no se si este sea el sitio adecuado para preguntarlo :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondo a tus preguntas, espero ser de ayuda:

> Lo primero es que no disponemos del código fuente de la aplicación,
>   solo tenemos la APK y el keystore. La APK está muy bien ofuscada lo
>   que hace que la Ingenieria Inversa sea casi imposible

En este caso asegura firmar correctamente tu .apk con el keystore, lo puedes realizar manualmente mediante [**apksigner**](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html), ejemplo:

```
apksigner sign --ks release.keystore --out production_app.apk debug_app.apk
```

existen dos cosas importante a considerar:

- Si es una actualización de la aplicación, el .apk debe tener el mismo paquete de aplicación que la actual versión (package id).
- Es estrictamente necesario firmar con el mismo keystore o certificado que se firmo la aplicación actual.

> Lo segundo es que, al haber suspendido la app Google Play, no podemos
>   eliminar la antigua app y subir una nueva con el mismo nombre de
>   paquete.

Si tu aplicación fue suspendida en Google Play, **no podrás subir una actualización**, debes subir una nueva aplicación con un nuevo paquete de aplicación (package id).

En cuanto a este problema que comentas:

> "Subiste un archivo APK firmado con un certificado restringido. Debes
>   subir un archivo APK firmado con tu propio certificado."

te listo dos causas :

- El .apk que intentas subir no fue firmado con un keystore o certificado, revisa que no estes usando uno de debug.
- Una causa que para muchos es "rara", en ocasiones surge porque el dispositivo donde deseas realizar esta tarea no tiene una fecha/hora correcta, te lo comento porque sucedía constantemente en una pc que controlaba sus fecha/hora manualmente.

Ahora no tengo ese problema ya que la fecha/hora de mi pc esta sincronizada con la red.

---

Hay cosas que te recomendaría,

- Asegurar tener el código respaldado y usar algún sistema de versionamiento de código.
- Respaldar y guardar en un lugar seguro el keystore o certificado con el cual firmas tu aplicación a Google Playstore.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Todo solucionado, el error era al firmar el apk!

Comment: Un placer Kike, pensaba que probablemente no tenian el keystore o que el .apk se habia generado con otro paquete; lo tuviste que firmar manualmente con apksigner?

Comment: Hola!
Dije que si tenia el keystore:

Comment: "Lo primero es que no disponemos del código fuente de la aplicación, solo tenemos la APK y el keystore. La APK está muy bien ofuscada lo que hace que la Ingenieria Inversa sea casi imposible.
"

Comment: Utilice una app para firmarla que se llama APK Signer!

Comment: Si! de hecho esa app usa precisamente las utilerías del SDK solo que en una aplicación, perfecto!